# Loading class with main method first and then manually loading other classes

Tags: java

I'm reading Core Java by Cay Horstmann.
There is an excerpt here that I can't understand:

> At startup, the class containing your mainmethod is loaded. It loads
>   all  classes that it needs. Each of those loaded classes loads the
>   classes that  it needs, and so on. That can take a long time for a big
>   application,  frustrating the user. You can give users of your program the illusion of a faster
>   start with the following trick. Make sure that the class containing themainmethod does not 
>   explicitly refer to other classes. First display a splash screen. Then manually force the loading 
>   of other classes by calling Class.forName.

Could you give me a small example of code so that I could understand it?

Answer (score 2):

The trick referred to in the quote is basically a way to give the user an illusion that the application loads faster by displaying the splash screen "right away" after invoking the program and only then starting to load classes.

Assume the main class of your application is `TheActualApplication`.
So, if you make `FastSplash` the startup class of your application, the splash screen may get displayed sooner than when `SlowSplash` is used as the main class.

```
public class FastSplasher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SplashWindow.splash(Splasher.class.getResource("splash.gif"));
         SplashWindow.invokeMain("TheActualApplication", args);
         SplashWindow.disposeSplash();
     }
 }

public class SlowSplasher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SplashWindow.splash(Splasher.class.getResource("splash.gif"));
         TheActualApplication.main(args);
         SplashWindow.disposeSplash();
     }
 }
```

The reason why the splash screen *may* occur sooner when using `FastSplash` is because today's Java VMs typically have [lazy class resolution](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/eagerandlazy.html) turned on and thus you may not see big difference. In the case of eager class resolution, the splash in `SlowSplasher` will only be displayed after all classes used in the `TheActualApplication` have been loaded. In `FastSplasher` the splash screen appears right away because the class `TheActualApplication` is loaded dynamically at runtime using reflection and cannot be resolved statically and thus loaded at startup.

Comment: Could you clarify what dou you imply when saying "you may not see big difference"? You mean that overall time passing from the start of an application to the moment the user can start using it will be the same? You mean that the splash screen in the FastSplasher will appear almost at once whereas in the SlowSplasher case it will appear only when it is almost unnecessary? In this case the comment below by Katona is really useful. As in Java 6 you can load a splash screen at the very beginning.

Comment: Yes, the trick won't speed up the time it takes for the application to become useful. But lazy class resolution, on the other hand, actually speeds the time up, as all classes referenced from the whole program are unlikely to be used in the first screen displayed to the user. From the splash screen perspective, Katona has a very good point. You should try both approaches and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that statement is still valid and useful. According to the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html), splash screens can be  displayed before the start of the JVM from Java 6, so the trick shown in other answers might not be necessary.

Comment: An excellent point! But to utilize that feature you need to give the splash image at commant line: `java -splash:<file name> <class name>`

Comment: The book is revised and updated for Java SE 6. So, judging from this, this hint must be useful. But I can't catch how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass` and `MyClass2` will be loaded after application startup

```
class MyClass {
  static {  System.out.println("MyClass loaded"); }
  private MyClass2 ref;
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
     System.out.println("Starting application...");
     Class.forName("MyClass");
  }
}
```